# How can I loop inside of try/catch phrase, and render on browser successfully in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, try-catch

I am making a get request inside a 'try-catch phrase' and the data is an array of objects. I want to loop through the array, and access each object's 'message' property. Then I'm trying to append its value(a string) as a 'li' to the 'ul' tag of body.

The problem is that the appending li to ul inside of the loop does not work at all. Nothing is appended.

I have tried writing the logic outside of the loop, and it does append successfully(the commented portion).

I am not seeing any of the console.logs inside the loop as well.

Here is the code:

```
let cache = {};
async function getMsg() {
try { 
    let res = await fetch('/api/getMsg');
    console.log('res', res)
    let data = await res.json();
    console.log('got data', data);

    const ul = document.getElementById('message-list');
    ul.innerHTML = 'List of messages';

    // data is an array whose elements are message objects
    data.forEach((obj)=> {
        // if (!cache[obj._id]) {
            const list = document.createElement('li');
            const button = document.createElement('button');

            list.innerText = obj.message;
            console.log(list)
            button.innerText = 'Delete';
            button.setAttribute('class', 'del');

            // button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            //     fetch(`/api/${obj._id}`)
            //         .then(res => res.json())
            //         .then(data => {
            //             window.alert(`Message with id of ${data} has been deleted!`);
            //         })
            // });
            
            ul.appendChild(list)
            ul.appendChild(button);
            cache.obj._id = obj.message;
       // }
    });
} catch {
    (err => console.log(err));
}
```

}
window.addEventListener("load", getMsg);

How can I make it succesfully append? I have also tried using a for loop, instead of the forEach method! I am successfully receiving all data from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try/catch has nothing to do with your problem. You are trying to append the same node several times and it cannot be done.
You can either create (`document.createElement('whatever')`) in every loop iteration or clone it, like here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode: `let p = document.getElementById("para1"); let p_prime = p.cloneNode(true)`

Creating a new node:

```js
let cache = {};
async function getMsg() {
try { 
    let res = await fetch('/api/getMsg');
    console.log('res', res)
    let data = await res.json();
    console.log('got data', data);

    const list = document.createElement('li')
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    const ul = document.getElementById('message-list');

    // ul.appendChild(list)
    // ul.appendChild(button);

    // data is an array whose elements are message objects
    data.forEach((obj)=> {
        if (!cache[obj._id]) {
            const list = document.createElement('li') // NEW!
            const button = document.createElement('button'); // NEW!

            list.innerText(obj.message);
            console.log(list)
            button.innerText('Delete');
            button.setAttribute('class', 'del');

            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                fetch(`/api/${obj._id}`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        window.alert(`Message with id of ${data} has been deleted!`);
                    })
            });
            
            ul.appendChild(list)
            ul.appendChild(button);
            cache.obj._id = obj.message;
        }
    });
} catch {
    (err => console.log(err));
}
```

Cloning a node:

```js
let cache = {};
async function getMsg() {
try { 
    let res = await fetch('/api/getMsg');
    console.log('res', res)
    let data = await res.json();
    console.log('got data', data);

    const list = document.createElement('li')
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    const ul = document.getElementById('message-list');

    // ul.appendChild(list)
    // ul.appendChild(button);

    // data is an array whose elements are message objects
    data.forEach((obj)=> {
        if (!cache[obj._id]) {
            const newList = list.cloneNode(true); // NEW!
            const newButton = button.cloneNode(true); // NEW!

            newList.innerText(obj.message); // NEW
            console.log(newList) // NEW
            newButton.innerText('Delete'); // NEW
            newButton.setAttribute('class', 'del'); // NEW

            newButton.addEventListener('click', () => {  // NEW
                fetch(`/api/${obj._id}`) 
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        window.alert(`Message with id of ${data} has been deleted!`);
                    })
            });
            
            ul.appendChild(newList) // NEW
            ul.appendChild(newButton); // NEW
            cache.obj._id = obj.message;
        }
    });
} catch {
    (err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Hey @IvanD thank you very much. however, it still doesn't render any li tags in the browser.. any ideas why?
This is what I get in the console, but I'm think it's irrelevant to this issue: 'DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/injectGlobalHook.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME'

Comment: This error 99% has nothing to do with the code, i.e. it's not what's failing the code

Comment: I do not have the complete code to help you at the moment. Can you modify your question so you have a runnable example?

Comment: I have figured it out. li tags were not rendering anything because 'innerText' is not a function.  I am using it as 'list.innerText(obj.message);' but it should be 'list.innerText = obj.message;'
Thanks you!!

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: Yes, I definitely will! But I'm encountering just one more problem. So the li tag and button is appending and showing, but only one the first instance is showing.(just one list and button rendering). I thought the forEach method would iterate through the array of objects. Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: each object looks like this:{
    created_at: 2020-10-25T07:50:39.431Z,
    _id: 5f952e5696bbd22a0d4809e1,
    message: 's',
    password: 's',
    __v: 0
  }

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. Let's clarify: 1) When you inspect "ul", do you see several 'button"+"li" elements or just one pair? 2) What is the length of your `data` array?

Comment: 1)  I just see one pair, as opposed to 4 expected pairs.
2) the length is 4

So I was expecting to see 4 li, button pairs from the 'forEach' logic, but am seeing only one pair. I have read over the code and I am not sure why.
Only seeing:
<ul>
<li>s</li> 
<button class="del">Delete</button>
</ul>

Comment: You have `if (!cache[obj._id])`, so it's the first place where having 4 items in a `data` array can become 1, the other 3 do not satisfy the condition. Add a `console.log(cache[obj._id]) to check it

Comment: even if I remove the if statement, it is not rendering. I'd appreciate if you'd take a final look

Comment: wow it works with a for... of loop, but not with forEach. thank you